# What was done with the orders of the cohanim during a leap year?

Tags: halacha, calendar, kohen-priest

In 1 Chronicles chapter 24 David set out orders for the cohanim to serve in the Beis Hamikdash. What he established is intuitive for a 12 month year, but what was done in a 13 month year? If possible, where may I find discussion not only on what was done, but the underlying debate and justification for the decision.

Comment: It's a 24 week rotation, so they didn't get the same time each year anyway.

Comment: @heshy 48 + pesach + sukkot is pretty close

Comment: @DoubleAA do you skip Pesach and Sukkot?  Sukkah 5:7 talks about משמר שזמנו קבוע on Yom Tov.  Anyway if it's not exactly right that shows they didn't care about it drifting through the year, however slowly.

Comment: I thought all of them would show up for the regalim Pesach Shavuot and Sukkot. With those three and repeating the normal 24 once gives 51 weeks which is tantalizingly close to a lunar year. That is also what spurred my question. I assumed there'd be a healthy argument on the matter or at least some haggadic passage in Talmud that explains.

Comment: I know that Bereichos b’Cheshbon discusses this question, but I haven’t seen a copy of that Sefer in years that I could look this up. In his first piece there, he explains how the Mishmaros lined up over the course of a full calendar cycle.

Comment: Thanks @DonielF a lead is better than what I had before.

Comment: @KenGoss A lot of editions of Mircheves HaMishnah on the Rambam’s Mishnah Torah include it in the back. Or so I’m told - like I said, I haven’t seen a copy of Breichos b’Cheshbon in years. But you might have some better luck.

Comment: @DonielF Do you happen to recall the judgment/protocol in the case of a leap year?

Comment: His general assumption IIRC is in line with Heshy’s assumption above that each Mishmar got a week, and while everyone served on Yom Tov it was primarily one Mishmar’s week. With that said, even non-leap years get complicated really quickly. And that’s where the math kicks in.